# Filter array of objects on all properties value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am really surprised I haven't been able to find anything related to my question. I am looking for a fast way to filter my array of objects based on a user text input.

Assume I have this array:

```
let data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Jean",
  "last_name": "Owens",
  "email": "jowens0@google.ru",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Marie",
  "last_name": "Morris",
  "email": "mmorris1@engadget.com",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "Larry",
  "last_name": "Wallace",
  "email": "lwallace2@example.com",
  "gender": "Male"
}];
```

User writes "s", the expected result would be:

```
let result = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Jean",
  "last_name": "Owens",
  "email": "jowens0@google.ru",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Marie",
  "last_name": "Morris",
  "email": "mmorris1@engadget.com",
  "gender": "Female"
}]
```

I could use the filter function in such a way:

```
let = searchText = "s";
    let result = data.filter(object=>{
      for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          return object[property].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        }
      }
    });
```

So I am wondering if there are better alternatives to this solution?

--Here is a working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8mhtjs5/5/) thanks to KoolShams

--[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i1it9PZ7WMzwpsopT7pS?p=preview) for benchmark purposes (tested with 2k data)

Comment: In this case a research with "l" will return you the whole data becouse "l" is part of either "male" or "female"...... Strange behavior

Comment: Yes? This is exactly what I want :)

Comment: Created a fiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/d8mhtjs5/5/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @KoolShams, I will add it to the question !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys()` and `some()` instead.

```js
let data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Jean",
  "last_name": "Owens",
  "email": "jowens0@google.ru",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Marie",
  "last_name": "Morris",
  "email": "mmorris1@engadget.com",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "Larry",
  "last_name": "Wallace",
  "email": "lwallace2@example.com",
  "gender": "Male"
}];

var result = data.filter(function(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).some(function(k) {
    return o[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('s') != -1;
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice, I like it, would the some function be faster than the loop ?

Comment: Not sure about that, if this is right way to test it it seems that loop is always faster https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1253/

Comment: I have tested with 2k data and a few different strings and the loop is definitely faster: https://plnkr.co/edit/i1it9PZ7WMzwpsopT7pS?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and omit `hasOwnProperty`.

This solution features [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
let data = [{ "id": 1, "first_name": "Jean", "last_name": "Owens", "email": "jowens0@google.ru", "gender": "Female" }, { "id": 2, "first_name": "Marie", "last_name": "Morris", "email": "mmorris1@engadget.com", "gender": "Female" }, { "id": 3, "first_name": "Larry", "last_name": "Wallace", "email": "lwallace2@example.com", "gender": "Male" }],
    searchText = "s",
    result = data.filter(o => 
        Object.keys(o).some(k => 
            o[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) !== -1));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For a better performance, you could store the keys in advance and iterate the keys, without using `Object.keys` for all objects in the array, if they are uniform.

```js
let data = [{ "id": 1, "first_name": "Jean", "last_name": "Owens", "email": "jowens0@google.ru", "gender": "Female" }, { "id": 2, "first_name": "Marie", "last_name": "Morris", "email": "mmorris1@engadget.com", "gender": "Female" }, { "id": 3, "first_name": "Larry", "last_name": "Wallace", "email": "lwallace2@example.com", "gender": "Male" }],
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]),
    searchText = "s",
    result = data.filter(o => 
        keys.some(k => 
            o[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) !== -1));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I added your solution to my benchmark, which I've added to the question, the loop is still the fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use any **lodash's** collection related function to object and it will iterate over values. Also you can use directly `_.toLower` to any string or number or Boolean and it will handle all the corner cases, so if you want a easier solution, and well structured code then here you go:

`data.filter(o=>_.some(o, v => _.toLower(v).indexOf('s')>-1))`

Here is the working example:

```js
let data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Jean",
  "last_name": "Owens",
  "email": "jowens0@google.ru",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Marie",
  "last_name": "Morris",
  "email": "mmorris1@engadget.com",
  "gender": "Female"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "Larry",
  "last_name": "Wallace",
  "email": "lwallace2@example.com",
  "gender": "Male"
}];

var sTxt = 's';

var res = data.filter(o=>_.some(o, v =>_.toLower(v).indexOf(sTxt)>-1))

console.log('Result: ', JSON.stringify(res,null,'    '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```