# Filter through a few objects in massive array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter through a few objects in a massive array, please find a few lines of it below:

```js
var dest = [{
  "city": "Glendale",
  "country": "Armenia",
  "admin_name": "Adana Eyalet"
}, {
  "city": "Globe",
  "country": "United States, USA",
  "admin_name": "Arizona"
}, {
  "city": "Kingman-Butler",
  "country": "United Kingdom",
  "admin_name": "Wales"
}]
```

And I have only one input field to search through these objects - city, country.

I am using the following code:

```js
var admin_name = dest.filter(function(item) {
  return item['admin_name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1
});
```

But haven't got a clue how to achieve my task. Sorry just started learning javascript.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want all the objects that have the value with input string?

Comment: Hi @adiga I will need a new array to display the results

Comment: [Filter array of objects on all properties value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817829)

Comment: Thanks @adiga is there any way I can filter through just city and country but not admin_name?

Comment: `dest.filter(item => item.city.includes(searchText) || item.country.includes(searchText))`

Comment: Stop reinventing the wheel, use the community - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter `_.filter(dest,{city: 'great city', country:'great country'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one:

```js
   var dest = [
        { city: "Glendale", country: "Armenia", admin_name: "Adana Eyalet" },
        { city: "Globe", country: "United States, USA", admin_name: "Arizona" },
        { city: "Kingman-Butler", country: "United Kingdom", admin_name: "Wales" },
    ];

    function searchInAllProp(object, textsearch) {
        for (a in object)
            if (object[a].includes(textsearch))
                return object;
        return undefined;
    }

   let f = dest.filter(t => searchInAllProp(t, "United"));

    console.log(f);
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning, but I need to display the full object(city,country and admin_name) not just the result and make search through city and country only.

Comment: You need to return the object that contains a search key?

Comment: @qqruza I updated my code pleas check it.

Answer (score 0):

Had too much time to make it interactive.

```js
const searchBtn = document.querySelector("#search-btn");

var dest = [
    { "city": "Glendale", "country": "Armenia", "admin_name": "Adana Eyalet" },
    { "city": "Globe", "country": "United States, USA", "admin_name": "Arizona" },
    { "city": "Kingman-Butler", "country": "United Kingdom", "admin_name": "Wales" }
];

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const searchText = document.querySelector("#search-text").value;
    const radio = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
    const arr = Array.from(radio);
    const searchKey =  arr.find(item => item.checked).id;
    if(searchKey) {
        const filteredArray = dest.filter(item => {
            return item[searchKey].toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase()
        });
        document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = filteredArray.length ? JSON.stringify(filteredArray) : "No results found";
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-text" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" id="city" name="search-param">
<label>City</label>
<input type="radio" id="country" name="search-param">
<label>Country</label>
<br />
<br />
<button type="button" id="search-btn"> Search !! </button>
<br />
<br />
<span id="results"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you @jateen By design I cannot choose which of objects to choose. It should work the same way as Google Flights....

Comment: Ohh ! Should've mentioned that earlier mate. But anyways I had fun making this. Good old vanilla.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help @jateen